# django custom form validation with foreign keys

Tags: django, forms, validation, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following models:

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    ...

class Demo(models.Model):
    computers = models.ManyToManyField(Computer)
    ...

class Scenario(models.Model):
    demo = models.ForeignKey(Demo)
    ...

class Setting(models.Model):
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario)
    computer = models.ForeignKey(Computer)
```

Basically a Demo uses multiple computers. A demo also has multiple scenarios. Each scenario has some settings and each setting configures a computer.

My problem is while using the django Admin site to add a scenario, after the user selects a demo in the drop down list and configures the settings for some computers, I need to validate that the computers in the settings are actually in the demo.

I've poured through the django documentation, online sites, and tried everything I can think of and still can't get this work.

I can't use the custom form validation because although I could get the 'demo' object from the cleaned_data in the scenario form, I can't seem to get access to the settings that get submitted with the form. If I do model level validation by overriding 'clean', that only works when I change a scenario not when I add a new one because the computer_set is empty for new ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a custom form to your `SettingInline` (I'm assuming from your post that `Setting` is an inline for `Scenario`).

You mention you can't use form validation but I don't see a reason why you'd need access to every other setting. If you want access to the other settings (say validation that involves all submitted settings) I'd override the `formset` itself.

```
class SettingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Setting

    def clean_computer(self):
        computer = self.cleaned_data.get('computer')
        if not self.instance.scenario.demo.computers.filter(computer=computer).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Computer not in demo")
        return computer

class SettingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Setting
    form = SettingForm
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although this works for editing an existing scenario, it does not work while adding a new scenario. I get a DoesNotExist exception. I'm guessing its because self.instance does not exist yet.

Comment: Where does the DoesNotExist get raised from? self.instance will always exist; it may not have a PK, but it will be a real instance. The foreign key should exist too..